# cypress typescript intercept query compile error

Tags: typescript, cypress

This is my code

```
  cy.intercept(
    {
      url: 'someurl',
      query: {
        somevalue: 1
      }
    },
    () => {
      return {
        images: 'hello'
      };
    }
  ).as('getMovieList');
  cy.wait('@getMovieList');
```

If I remove query then the typescript compile error disappears.

> {
> "resource": "/c:/baps/react_all/test/tmdb/tmdb-test/cypress/support/step_definitions/intercept/movies.ts",
> "owner": "typescript",
> "code": "2769",
> "severity": 8,
> "message": "No overload matches this call.\n  Overload 1 of 3, '(url: RouteMatcher, response?: RouteHandler | undefined): Chainable', gave the following error.\n    Type '{ page: number; }' is not assignable to type 'DictMatcher'.\n      Property 'page' is incompatible with index signature.\n        Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'StringMatcher'.\n  Overload 2 of 3, '(method: Method, url: RouteMatcher, response?: RouteHandler | undefined): Chainable', gave the following error.\n    Argument of type '{ url: string; query: { page: number; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Method'.\n      Type '{ url: string; query: { page: number; }; }' is not assignable to type '"unsubscribe"'.",
> "source": "ts",
> "startLineNumber": 50,
> "startColumn": 3,
> "endLineNumber": 60,
> "endColumn": 4
> }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved problem. It needs to be a string

```js
cy.intercept(
    {
      url: 'someurl',
      query: {
        somevalue: '1'
      }
    },
    () => {
      return {
        images: 'hello'
      };
    }
  ).as('getMovieList');
  cy.wait('@getMovieList');
```